# Is there anyway to insert data into table based off a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a value into a MySQL database, and I want the value to be the result of a query + 1. Is it there any way to do this similar to my posted code?

```
INSERT INTO transaction (transactionId,userId)
VALUES 
    (select (
    SELECT max(transactionId) FROM `transaction` WHERE userId = 26) + 1),26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase the query as as `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (transactionId, userId)
    SELECT max(transactionId) + 1, 26
    FROM transaction
    WHERE userId = 26;
```

Actually, this is safer:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (transactionId, userId)
    SELECT coalesce(max(transactionId) + 1, 1), 26
    FROM transaction
    WHERE userId = 26;
```

But, either version still has race conditions.  You should really set up `transactionId` to be an auto-increment column across *all* users.  This guarantees uniqueness on each row and doesn't suffer from race conditions.

Comment: You are a life savior!

Comment: Is there a way that I can have just transactionId auto-increment for each user such that user 1 can have transactionId 1 and user 2 can have transactionId 1 as each row would still be unique?

Comment: @jh95 . . . That is generally not easy to do in SQL, unless you think triggers are easy.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for all your help!